# How to add lightbox to a field in grid?

Tags: grid, lightbox, tapestry

I have a Tapestry 5 (5.3.4) app that shows a grid with some values. I want to add a field in grid that will show a image icon (i have done this) and when user clicks on the icon, lightbox will show the requested image (I need help with this part). The problem is the lightbox because the JavaScript is not called and the image is shown in single page (URL to image - resource on server). I have tried to open lightbox outside of a grid and it worked, but won't inside. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for posting this question, but the answer was simple collision between jQuery and Prototype. Just needed to add `$.noConflict().` to jQuery library. So lightbox was possible after all.